How to get diagnostic info for node.js hang?
We are using node 18.18.2 for windows in our CI.  It is hanging, and after 30 minutes, are wrapper process kills it.  When it hasn't killed it, I did get a dump of node, but it didn't really show much.  How can I augment our wrapper process to, instead of just kill node after reaching 30 minutes, to get diagnostic info like stack trace and variables and such to determine where it is hanging.

You could try strace

Missed that this was Windows. Doesn't visual studio have a deubgger? Also can't hurt to update your node.

I am debugging in VS, but it is unclear to me where in the program it actually is. It appears to be waiting on I/O completion port.  I was hoping to gleen some status about the js program that node is rubbing
